# Rapidapi & 401 unauthorized Response

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney, rapidapi

I am working with Rad Studio (Delphi) and I am trying to connect to a RapidApi Endpoint via a Rest Component of Rad Studio.
Although I use the "x-rapidapi-key" & "x-rapidapi-host" as parameters on the Rest Component, I get a 401 unauthorized Response.
Any Ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you use. Preferably, create a minimal reproducible example. Follow those guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear but probably you need to pass `x-rapidapi-host` and `x-rapidapi-key` as the request headers, not parameters.

For example, try something like this

```
var axios = require("axios").default;

var options = {   
     method: 'GET',   
     url: 'https://example.p.rapidapi.com/',   
     params: {query: 'something here'},
     headers: {
        'x-rapidapi-host': 'example.p.rapidapi.com',
        'x-rapidapi-key': '12345'
     }
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
   console.log(response.data); 
}).catch(function (error) {     
   console.error(error); 
});
```